# Preprocessor symbol for Wayland, Xlib, XCB, MIR window systems

Tags: c, linux, xlib, xcb, vulkan

On Vulkan docs we have the following regarding WSI Platform:

> The Vulkan API does not define any type of platform object. Platform-specific WSI extensions are defined, which contain platform-specific functions for using WSI. Use of these extensions is guarded by preprocessor symbols.
>
> • VK_USE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_KHR - Android
>
> • VK_USE_PLATFORM_MIR_KHR - Mir
>
> • VK_USE_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_KHR - Wayland
>
> • VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR - Microsoft Windows
>
> • VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR - X Window System, using the XCB library
>
> • VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR - X Window System, using the Xlib library

I understand that I should pick a platform or a Window System, and then define the correct symbol prior to compile. When compiling against Android or Windows, I can just write something like below:

```
#if defined(ANDROID) || defined (__ANDROID__)
  #define VK_USE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_KHR 1
#elif defined(_WIN32)
  #define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR 1
#endif
```

So far, OK. Android and Windows has their own unique window system, which is good enough. But Linux has several windowing systems - Xlib, XCB, Wayland and MIR, afaik.

I'd like to know if there is a C/C++ **preprocessor symbol** which may help to know which Window System is the one used by that environment, so can write generic code able to deal with each API, without messing then.

Comment: All these things may be present simultaneously in any given Linux installation. There is no way to select the preferred one automatically. That would require reading user's mind. There's no way to detect any of them with a preprocessor symbol either.

Comment: Thank for your replay. Once I have this compiled, do you think it's possible to discover, at runtime how, windowing system is active ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. If you have DISPLAY environment variable set, chances are, you have X11 running. (Xlib and XCB are two client libraries that talk to the same X11 graphic system). To detect Wayland, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used. To detect Mir, http://askubuntu.com/questions/330862/how-do-i-find-out-if-my-system-is-using-mir. Note that bith Mir and Wayand probably run an X11 emulation layer.

Comment: @n.m. I'll try it and  give a feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xlib and XCB are two libraries that can both be used interchangeably to interface with an X11 windowing server on Linux. If you need your application to be compatible with older Linux systems, build for Xlib; otherwise, use XCB.

Wayland and Mir are both still highly experimental (as of May 2016), and can safely be ignored.

Comment: Thank for your replay. As it is a library to be distributed, I guess I'll have to build a .so lib for each windowing system. As Vulkan requires entry points only, (xcb_connection_t * and xcb_visualid_t, or Display* and Window)  do you think  it's possible to compile Xlib and XCB in a single bridge library ?

Comment: Already answered in comments to question. I'll use a unique * .so lib, with all Vulkan interfaces to Linux enabled: Xlib, XCB, Wayland and Mir. I hope to have all headers available and no conflicts between then !

Answer (score 2):

If you are the one interfacing with the windowing system then you already know what preprocessor symbol you need.

If you are not then as the application code (using a wrapper around the native windowing) then you would ask the wrapper for the vkSurface, if that is not available then raise an issue with the wrapper's maintainers.

If you are a vulkan library then you should be able to handle all linux windowing options. If you enable all preprocessor symbols and manually load the required function as needed depending on which function the application calls.

Comment: @ratchet_freak Hi ! I'm building object oriented Vulkan  API on top of C API. Solved those points related in this question, I'll do what you sad in 3rd paragraph: at Linux, enable all Vulkan preprocessors related to Linux windowing system (w.s.) , and compile all of then at once. In the middleware, I still have to discover which one is the proper w.s. to be selected at runtime. The application itself  may use Java AWT/Swing or a native GLFW / SDL to interact with current "X".